# Regex For Anchor Tag Pegging CPU

Tags: c#, regex, performance

So I have broke my regex in half and found this half is causing the cpu to peg under load.  What are some performance savers I could do to help?  I can't really find any spots to shave off.

```
private string pattern = 
@"(<a\s+href\s*=\s*(\""|')http(s)?://(www.)?([a-z0-9]+\-?[a-z0-9]+\.)?wordpress.org(\""|'))";

Regex wordPressPattern = new Regex(regexPattern, RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Singleline);
```

Comment: Does compiling the regex make a difference?

Comment: @ChuckConway i updated the code, I do mark it as compiled.  I believe that's what you are referring to.

Comment: How big is the string being evaluated?

Comment: @ChuckConway it's looking that the raw html of a page.  So can be lengthy.

Comment: Larger than one of these? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:LongPages

Comment: @JasonSperske No, that's neat though.  These are more generic pages and some blogs.

Comment: Use the HTMLAgilityPack to parse html.  Don't use regex.  http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/47589

Comment: The usual advice applies here...don't parse HTML with a regex (user a parser like HTML Agility Pack). That said, a regex against a 50-100K of HTML usually isn't that expensive.

Comment: That said, if you are running a loop wherein you are parsing hundreds of pages at a time, I would except to see CPU usage spike.

Comment: As an aside, did you mean `(www\.)` instead of `(www.)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only thing that jumps out at me as a performance sink is this part:

```
[a-z0-9]+\-?[a-z0-9]+
```

The idea is to match hyphenated words like `luxury-yacht` or `THX-1138`, while still allowing words *without* hyphens.  Trouble is, if there's no hyphen, the regex engine still has to choose how to distribute the characters between the first `[a-z0-9]+` and the second one.  If it tries to match `word` as `w-o-r-(no hyphen)-d`, and something later in the regex fails to match, it has to come back and try `w-o-(no hyphen)-r-d`, and so on.  These efforts are pointless, but the regex engine has no way to know that.  You need to give it a little help, like so:

```
[a-z0-9]+(-[a-z0-9]+)?
```

Now you're saying, "If you run out of alphanumerics, and the next character is a hyphen, try to match some more alphanumerics.  Otherwise, go on to the next part."  But you don't need to be so specific in this case; you're trying to *find* the URLs, not validate them.  I recommend you replace that part with:

```
[a-z0-9-]+
```

This also allows it to match words with more than one hyphen (e.g., `james-bond`, but also `james-bond-007`).

You also have a lot of unnecessary capturing groups.  You don't seem to be using the captures, so you might as well use the `ExplicitCapture` option to improve performance a little more.  But most of the groups don't seem to be needed even for pure grouping purposes.  I suggest you try this regex:

```
@"<a\s+href\s*=\s*[""']https?://([a-z0-9-]+\.)+wordpress\.org[""']"
```

...with these options:

```
RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.ExplicitCapture
```